# Flutter extra / unwanted space above keyboard

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a weird extra spacing when clicking into a textfield in Flutter, that above the normal iOS keyboard some extra grey box appears. Can anyone help me where this comes from and how to get rid of it? The video shows how it appears.

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: A quick check, see if you have a `Scaffold` as a child for another `Scaffold`. Usually happens with multiple `Scaffold`s in same page.

Comment: how are we suppose to help you if you cannot see the code, which you have used to build this screen

Answer (score 8):

Found it, thanks for the help!

I have a setup with tabs at the bottom and had in from former tests these 2 properties set to false in the scaffold setup:

```
      child: Scaffold(
//        resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false, <-- caused the extra space
//        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false, <-- caused the extra space
        body: buildTabs(context),
```

Comment: Using dev tools widget inspector would be handy to find if there are multiple scaffold somewhere.

Answer (score 5):

This issue happens when you nest a `Scaffold` inside another `Scaffold`.

I added the following property to the outer Scaffold to solve the issue:

```
Scaffold(
  ...
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
)
```

Answer (score 4):

This is happens when you have a scaffold that is a child of another scaffold and one of them has backgroundColor: property set to a value. You can set scaffoldBackgroundColor: property in your theme and remove color properties in the scaffold itself and this should fix your issue!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had this structure which cased the whitespace:

```
Scaffold(child: PageView(children: [//some containers, Container(child: SingleChildScrollView( child: Column(children: [//some children widgets])))]));
```

then I moved the SingleChildScrollView from wrapping the column to wrap the first container and that fixed the issue

```
Scaffold(child: PageView(children: [//some containers, SingleChildScrollView( Container(child: Column(children: [//some children widgets])))]));
```

Answer (score 0):

This happen because we use white color in scaffold property backgroundColor
which cause an issue.

Remove Color property from Parent Scaffold widget and if you want to use color in parent widget so you can use theme property scaffoldBackgroundColor.

Answer (score 0):

in my case it was [device_preview](https://pub.dev/packages/device_preview) package that cause the problem and the space disappeared when I disabled it.

```
void main() async {
  await init();
  runApp(DevicePreview(
    enabled: false,
    builder: (context) => const App(),
  ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

by adding this line to your scaffold widget, will resolve the issue.

```
resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
```